# In Snowflake, how to determine "Cloud Services" credits vs "Compute" credits?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake's web UI, go to 'Account' --> 'Billing & Usage'. Select one of the Warehouses on the left. Credit stats will appear. Drill into one by clicking on the magnifying glass. A new window will pop up with a stacked bar chart of credits used. The stacks consist of "Cloud Services" credits and "Compute" credits. I would like to know the detailed breakdown of items under each type of credit.

My goal is to increase performance and efficiency in our usage. But it's difficult to pinpoint some areas in need of improvement when Snowflake just reports "Compute" credits without any type of breakdown.

I have found the following pages:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html#

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-monitoring-usage.html#

One of them has some detail on "Cloud Services" credits, but I would like a little more detail (if it is available). I cannot find anything that lists what falls under "Compute" credits. In addition, I have familiarized myself a little with the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema. QUERY_HISTORY gives me great granular detail of "Cloud Services" usage. But again, I haven't found anything that breaks down "Compute" usage.

Anything I missed, or a point in the right direction would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Snowflake Compute credits are based on warehouse usage and is determined by the size of the warehouse and the amount of time that the warehouse is up and running.  Your best bet for detailed information on this is likely the following account_usage view:

Warehouse Metering History:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/warehouse_metering_history.html

This view provides you hourly credit consumption by warehouse.  It also includes the cloud services credits that for that hour by warehouse, as well.

Note that while you can get cloud services credits at the query_history level, that is not available for compute credits, since compute credits are based on the time the warehouse is running, not based on each query that is executed (for example, 5 queries could be running at the same time on the same warehouse, but you are only charged for the time the warehouse is running).

Hope this helps.  If you need clarification, add a comment below, and I can help answer further.